# What time was a recent question asked?

Tags: support

[Can I apply for a France visa while I'm visiting in the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83468/can-i-apply-for-a-france-visa-while-im-visiting-in-the-uk) was "asked yesterday" as was [Want to apply for France visa while visiting the UK](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/want-to-apply-for-france-visa-while-visiting-the-uk). Older questions show you the date and time of the post but newer ones don't seem to do that.

Or maybe they do and I'm just not familiar with how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you can get the time by hovering with your mouse over 'yesterday'. Time seems to be in UTC.

[image: Hover over time to see time]

Answer (score 4):

[Drat’s answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4087) points out how to hover to find out a specific time. This works for:

- asked, answered or modified on the main page or questions page
- time of posting of questions or answers on the speicific question pages
- time of modification on the specific question pages.

The text will read anything of the following, from recent to old:

- > *x* seconds ago
- > *x* minutes ago
- > *x* hours ago
- > yesterday
- > 2 days ago
- > `date` `monthname` `UTCtime`
- > `date` `monthname` `2-digit-year` `UTCtime`